# Append line to previous line where a column is split into multiple lines

Tags: text-processing

The description field value might be present in  multiple lines. I would like to put it into single line like below. The file will have fixed number of columns.

**Input File:**

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes  
101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free                
   |1|Fruits:||||   
102|2|Banana,      
Orange, Grapes  
Kiwi||||
```

Any line that does not contain "|" or the lines that contain "|" but the count of "|" in the line is equal to 4, then the line should be appended to the previous line which contains "|"

**Output File:**

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes      
101|0|Apple,Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free                 
   |1|Fruits:||||       
102|2|Banana,Orange, Grapes Kiwi||||
```

Comment: your output is unclear. For ex. the 2nd line doesn't fit any of conditions but it was appended to the 1st line. Elaborate your conditions OR update your output

Comment: 2nd Line should not be appended to the first line.. Updated the required output

Comment: It seems to me that what you might want is to rewrap the CSV file to a given width so that all of the rows have the same number of columns. Is that what you want or do you really just literally want to do what's stated in the question?

Comment: yes.. I want to rewrap the text file so that all of the rows have same number of columns

Comment: @Harish Did any of the answers below help? If so please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . If not please specify what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Python script that does what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- ascii -*-
"""rewrapcsv.py"""

import sys

datafile = sys.argv[1]
columns = int(sys.argv[2])

with open(datafile) as filehandle:
    buffer = []
    for line in filehandle:
        buffer.extend(line.strip().split('|'))

    while len(buffer) >= columns:
        print('|'.join(buffer[0:columns]))
        buffer = buffer[columns:]

    print('|'.join(buffer[0:columns]))
```

Here is an example data file (`data.csv`) taken from your question:

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes
101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free
|1|Fruits:||||
102|2|Banana,
Orange, Grapes Kiwi||||
```

Here is how you could run the script:

```bsh
python rewrapcsv.py data.csv 6
```

And here is the output:

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate
Notes|101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%
8.56|Free||1|Fruits:|
|||102|2|Banana,
Orange, Grapes Kiwi||||
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'|' 'r{ if (NF!=1 && NF!=5) print r; else { print r,$0; next } }{ r=$0 }' file
```

- `-F'|'` - field separator
- `r` - contains previous record

---

The output:

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes
101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free
   |1|Fruits:||||
102|2|Banana, Orange, Grapes Kiwi||||
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ex...

```
ex +'g/^\([^|]\+\(|[^|]*\)\{4}\|[^|]\+\)$/norm! kgJ' +wq file
```

Or, same thing but with "very magic" mode (the `\v` at the start of the pattern)...a bit easier on the eyes, IMO, as only the literal `|` need to be escaped...

```
ex +'g/\v^([^\|]+(\|[^\|]*){4}|[^\|]+)$/norm! kgJ' +wq file
```

Vim implements Ex in modern systems so if you know Vim these `ex` commands may look familiar. The first command (after the first `+`) is a "global" command. If one of the patterns (no `|` or four `|` in a line) is found then the Normal mode commands for moving up one line (`k`) and joining the line that follows (`gJ`) are executed.

This is one of the few portable solutions that **will update the file in-place**. (GNU's `sed -i`, for example, uses temp files).

Here's your input plus a test for the second pattern ("line doesn't contain |"):

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes  
101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free                
   |1|Fruits:||||   
102|2|Banana,      
Orange, Grapes    Kiwi||||
103|2|Watermelon,
Pear, Raspberry, Lime
```

Result:

```
Number|Level|Description|Unit|Rate|Special Rate|Notes
101|0|Apple, Orange, Banana||6.80%|8.56|Free
   |1|Fruits:||||
102|2|Banana,Orange, Grapes    Kiwi||||
103|2|Watermelon,Pear, Raspberry, Lime
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` solution:

```
sed -E -e :a -e '/(\|.*){6,}/!N;s/\n/ /;ta' file
```

The extended regular expression `(\|.*){6,}` matches a line with at least 6 bars in it. If the current line doesn't match that, append the next line (`!N`).

`s/\n/ /` replaces a newline with a space. If this replacement was made, it means that a line got appended, so we need to test again, so `ta` jumps to mark `:a` if the replacement was made. Done.